# SPfx Show More button with a different approach?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, splistitem

My Approach is

1. default 6 items, using  api query of the $top=6
2. If a button is pressed, clear screen, get all data using qpi query without $top6

Algorithm:

- Define a function to loadNews(boolean=false)
  This defaults to get 6 items only, API query with $top=6
- Create a button and onClick event pass true to the function
- If true is passed to the loadNews();
- this.forceUpdate();
- clear the contents of the data array
- fetch all data using another API query without $top=6

What will be another better approach that can boost performance?
Is it possible to add on show additional items without having to load all data again?

This is my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './A.module.scss';
import { IAProps } from './IAProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { PageContext } from "@microsoft/sp-page-context";
import { HttpClient, IHttpClientOptions, HttpClientResponse, SPHttpClient, ISPHttpClientOptions, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import {
  Environment,
  EnvironmentType
} from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {Button} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';

export interface ISPLists {
  value: ISPList[];
};

export interface Istate {
  ID:string;
  Title: string;
  isLoad?: boolean;
  Url:string;
    AttachmentFiles:{
      Name:string;
      Url:string;
    ServerRelativeUrl: string;

    };
}


export interface ISPList {
  ID:string;
  Title: string;
  Summary : string;
  NewsCategory: string;
  Created:string;
    AttachmentFiles:{
      Name:string,
      Url:string,
    ServerRelativeUrl: string,
    };

}






/*
MAIN STARTS HERE
2020-01-28
*/
export default class A extends React.Component<IAProps> {

constructor(props){
  super(props);

   this.loadNews();

   this.getListData=this.getListData.bind(this);
   this.geturl=this.geturl.bind(this);
   this.loadNews=this.loadNews.bind(this);
}



//variables to render html tags
private data:any =[];





private loadNews(showall=false){
  if(showall){
    this.data.length = 0;
    this.forceUpdate();
    this.getListData(showall);
  }else{
    this.getListData(showall); // show 6 item by default
  }

}



  public geturl(query:string){
    var path="/Lists/News/DispForm.aspx?ID=";
    var currdir=this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl;
   var result=currdir+path+query;
       return result;
   }



   private  async getListData(ShowAll) {
     var qurl;
      if (ShowAll)
     {
       qurl="/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('News')/items?$select=*,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles/Title&$orderby=ID desc";
     }else{
       qurl="/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('News')/items?$select=*,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles/Title&$orderby=ID desc&$top=6";
     }
    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose' } };
    this.props.SPHttpClient.get(this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl + qurl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, opt).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      response.json().then((json: any) => {

         for(let i=0;i<json.value.length;i++){
          var url=this.geturl(json.value[i].ID);

            this.data.push({
              ID:json.value[i].ID,
             Title:<a href={url} target="_blank">{json.value[i].Title}</a>,
             Desc:json.value[i].Description,
             More:url,
             summ:json.value[i].Summary,
             Url:<img className={styles.image} src={json.value[i].AttachmentFiles[0] ? json.value[i].AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQy7LYu4CcprObfi6O9Vt7TMhFfT0jKju7koQOdUKH3_ZXmqq2G&s'} />
              });  




             //   debugger;
               this.forceUpdate();
              }//close for
        });// close response.json
      });//close private getListData method

    }



  public render(): React.ReactElement<IAProps>{

       return (



        <div className={styles.thumbnails}>
        <div className={styles.title}>
          最新消息
            </div>

        {this.data.map((data)=>

          <div className={styles.box}>

                          {data.Url}

                          <div className={styles.p}>
                            {data.Title}
                          </div>
                              <div className={styles.h3}>
                                  {data.summ}
                              </div>
                                   <div className={styles.more}>
                                       <a href={data.More} target="_blank">More...</a>
                                   </div>

           </div>
        )}

        <div className={styles.showall}>
          <button onClick={() => this.loadNews(true)}>More </button>
        </div>
         </div>










    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While willman's critique of your code is correct (I was going to add all that into my answer as well - you should definitely be saving that data in `state`, not a class property, and relying on the fact that when you call `setState()`, React will automatically re-render, without having to call `forceUpdate()`), I want to answer your real question:

> What will be another better approach that can boost performance? Is it
>   possible to add on show additional items without having to load all
>   data again?

I would say you should only really be concerned with the "performance" of making API calls if you know you are going to have users dealing with extremely slow network connections.  The way I see it, you have a few options to do what you want: initially show only 6 items, and only show more if the users actively want to see more.

1. You could just automatically request all items with your initial API call, and not use `$top=6`, but when you get the data, only show the first 6 in the UI.  That way, if the users request to see more, you already have it all in memory and don't need to make another API call, you just show more of what you already have.
2. Do what you're planning to do - get the first 6 using `$top=6`, and if the users ask for more, just reload without `$top=6`.
3. I'm not sure *exactly* how it's exposed in the response when making requests through the `SPHttpClient` in SPFx, but when making straight REST API calls, if you use `$top`, there will be a `__next` property on the response object that has a URL for you to get the next items, the same number that you specified in your `$top`.  So in your case, if you did `$top=6`, your first API call would get the first 6 items, then in the response would also be a `__next` property with a URL you could use to get the next 6 items.

In any case, it really boils down to two approaches:

- Make one API call and load everything, and deal with what gets shown in your code, or
- Make multiple API calls

(My other suggestion to you, not related to API calls but related to React coding patters, would be to *not* start off your first API call from within the constructor.  You should do it from `componentDidMount`.  Here's some info on the [React lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class).)

Answer (score 1):

You should not be storing your results in a class variable and calling `forceUpdate`.  Instead, you should store the results in `state` ([see docs on state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)).  React is purposefully built to run your `render` method whenever `state` changes.  That way you don't have to blank anything out, when they click the button, the first 6 items stay there until your api call finished then is instantly replaced by the full dataset.

So, if you change add `resultData: Array` to your `IState`, and change your class definition to include IState, `extends React.Component<IAProps, IState>`, then change your api callback to something like this:

```
this.props.SPHttpClient.get(this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl + qurl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, opt).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      response.json().then((json: any) => {
         let tempResults = [];

         for(let i=0;i<json.value.length;i++){
          var url=this.geturl(json.value[i].ID);

            tempResults.push({
              ID:json.value[i].ID,
             Title:<a href={url} target="_blank">{json.value[i].Title}</a>,
             Desc:json.value[i].Description,
             More:url,
             summ:json.value[i].Summary,
             Url:<img className={styles.image} src={json.value[i].AttachmentFiles[0] ? json.value[i].AttachmentFiles[0].ServerRelativeUrl: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQy7LYu4CcprObfi6O9Vt7TMhFfT0jKju7koQOdUKH3_ZXmqq2G&s'} />
              });  

               this.setState( { resultData: tempResults });
              }//close for
        });// close response.json
```

Then finally change your render method to use `this.state.resultData.map` instead of `this.data.map`.

Now, with all of that said, once that is complete, you may want to implement paging so that the user can choose to get records in chunks or pages of ten or twenty at a time, instead of just choosing between 6 records or all.